# Binding the current time to the time field using datetimepicker in jquery

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I've two controls where one control is date and other is time. I'm using datetimepicker. For the date control, current date is appearing, but for the time field, time appears only when I click on it. How can I show current time before selecting?

This is how I've tried:

HTML:

```
<label for="Meeting Held On" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Meeting held On</label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MeetingHeldOn" name="MeetingHeldOn" value='<?php echo date_format(date_create($data->meetingheldon),"d-m-Y"); ?>'>
</div>
<label for="Meeting Started At" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Meeting Started At</label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MeetingStartedAt" name="MeetingStartedAt" value='<?php echo $data->meetingstartedat; ?>'>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#MeetingHeldOn").datetimepicker({ format: "DD-MM-YYYY" });
$("#MeetingStartedAt,#MeetingEndedAt").datetimepicker({ format: "HH:mm" });
```

What I want is, by default when the page is loaded, it should show the current time. After that I can make changes. So, for doing that, what should I add or change?

Comment: Its hard to get which datetimepicker you used as there are many developed with the same name with Bootstrap. One thing I can suggest you is to select the input box using jQuery selector and set the required value.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you use Twitter Bootstrap datetimepicker. 
Here is the working example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/7khwX/2/)

set the `value` attribute from backend in order to have initial date or time.